# Get variable from WWW call in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a PHP function which returns XML data. I am using C# Unity to retrieve the data to a string variable. I have done this.

In class Requestwww I have

```
public static text;
public IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
    {
       yield return www;
        // check for errors
        if (www.error == null)
        {   //Here I store result in a global variable
            text=www.text;
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }


    }

    public  IEnumerator getxml(string url )
   {

        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        if (www == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("www is null");
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("www is not null");
        }

        yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
        Debug.Log("xmltext here" + text);

    }
```

And in another class, I call getxml() to start the wwwrequest

```
Request wwwcall = gameObject.AddComponent<Requestwww>(); 
StartCoroutine(wwwcall.getxml("http://com.example/something.php")
//Here I tried to access the xmltext variable in Requestwww class
Debug.Log("retrived var"+Requestwww.text)
//But text seems tobe null
```

But it looks like, the variable Requestwww.text is always null when retried from another class. I don't get it. I called the Coroutine, wait for result, and then update the global varibale, but it seems like the moment I called it from another class, it has not been updated. What should I do? It has taken me a day aching for an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The answer

This happens because you don't wait for `StartCoroutine(wwwcall.getxml("http://com.example/something.php"));` to finish. If StartCoroutine is called without `yield return` it will return immediately. So, the solution is to wait for coroutine to finish (or to get rid of coroutines and wait for WWW to finish). You can do it either:

1. In Update method. Like this:

   ```
   public class RequestWWW
   {
       public bool IsDone
       {
           get;
           private set;
       }

       public string Text
       {
           get;
           private set;
       }

       public string Error
       {
           get;
           private set;
       }

       public IEnumerator GetXMLCoroutine(string url)
       {
           WWW www = new WWW(url);
           yield return www;
           IsDone = true;
           Error = www.error;
           Text = www.text;
       }
   }

   public class YourClass: MonoBehaviour
   {
       private RequestWWW wwwcall;

       private void SomeMethod()
       {
           wwwcall = new RequestWWW();
           StartCoroutine(wwwcall.GetXMLCoroutine("http://ya.ru"));
       }

       public void Update()
       {
           if (wwwcall != null && wwwcall.IsDone)
           {
               Debug.Log(wwwcall.Error);
               Debug.Log(wwwcall.Text);
               wwwcall = null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using callback. Like this:

   ```
   public static class RequestWWW
   {
       public delegate void RequestFinishedHandler(string error, string text);

       public static IEnumerator GetXMLCoroutine(string url, RequestFinishedHandler onFinish)
       {
           WWW www = new WWW(url);
           yield return www;
           if (onFinish != null)
               onFinish(www.error, www.text);
       }
   }

   public class YourClass: MonoBehaviour
   {
       private void SomeMethod()
       {
           StartCoroutine(RequestWWW.GetXMLCoroutine("http://ya.ru/", RequestFinished));
       }

       private void RequestFinished(string error, string text)
       {
           Debug.Log(error);
           Debug.Log(text);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome, man ! I was using isDone flag to wait, but the way you do it  is the most elegant !

Comment: I'm glad you liked it :)